# WIX Installer remove entry from XmlConfig element

Tags: wix

How to delete the "DrawListAddin" from this list with WIX XmlConfig ?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- instance">
    <string>ExplorerAddin</string>
    <string>DrawListAddin</string>
    <string>MyDataAddin</string>
  </ArrayOfString>
```

Result should look like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- instance">
    <string>ExplorerAddin</string>
    <string>MyDataAddin</string>
  </ArrayOfString>
```

i try multiple settings but nothing work .. the last version looks like this. Searching for the correct item and than remove it. The XML file gets modified but no changes.

```
<util:XmlConfig Id='XmlSettingsRemove' 
    On="install"
    File='[E3D31_INSTALL_DIR]DesignAddins.xml' 
    Node='element'
    Action='delete'                         
    VerifyPath="//*[\[]text() [\[]contains(.,'DrawListAddin')[\]][\]]" 
    ElementPath="//ArrayOfString" 
    Sequence='1' 
 />
```

this code bring an error message that the node could not be found but the "/.." at the end explicit selects the parent correct

```
<util:XmlConfig Id='XmlSettingsRemove' 
  On="install"
  File='[E3D31_INSTALL_DIR]DesignAddins.xml' 
  Node='element'
  Action='delete'                       
  VerifyPath="/ArrayOfString/string[\[]text()[\[]contains(.,'DrawListAddin')[\]][\]]" 
  ElementPath="/ArrayOfString/string[\[]text()[\[]contains(.,'DrawListAddin')[\]][\]]/.." 
  Sequence='1' 
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just for review .. here is the solution with a embedded script .. i put some placeholder into the code like "DO_SOME_HERE" ..

```
    <CustomAction Id="UnInstallUIFileSetProperty" Property="UnInstallUIFileExec" Value="[PLACE_YOUR_PATH_TO_XML_FILE_HERE]" />  
    <CustomAction Id="UnInstallUIFileExec" Script="vbscript" Execute='deferred' Impersonate='no' Return='ignore'>
  <![CDATA[                     
                    on error resume next
                    c=Session.Property("CustomActionData")
                    n=c+"ADD_THE_XML_FILENAME_HERE"                                         
                    
                    Set x = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")                                            
                    
                    x.async = False 
                    x.load(n)
                    
                    Set r = x.documentElement                       
                    Set l = r.getElementsByTagName("string")
                    For Each e In l                         
                        if InStr(e.text,"ENTER_SEARCHTEXT_HERE") then
                            e.ParentNode.removeChild(e)
                        end if
                    Next            
                    
                  if err.Number<>0 then
                    res=MsgBox("remove of addin failed: "+n)                        
                    else
                      x.Save(n)
                    end if
                
  ]]>
</CustomAction>
```